# how to save excel file using vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba

im stuck getting this error whenever i try to save excel in vb.. pleas someone help me what is wrong in this code:

```
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
        xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        xlWorkBook.SaveAs(Filename:="C:\Users\PB\Documents\thesis\bookrecord", FileFormat:="xlCSV")
        xlApp.Visible = True
```

the save statement gets the error Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

Comment: Put that inside a try-catch block and see what the exception message tells you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a simple test using the enum type for file format and it created the file without error. If this does nto work, please show a bit more of your coode:

```
    xlWorkBook.SaveAs(Filename:="C:\Users\PB\Documents\thesis\bookrecord", FileFormat:=XlFileFormat.xlCSV)
```